# from nav_msgs::path to base_local_planner::Trajectory?

Tags: ros, navigation, nav-msgs, move-base, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I am writing a plugin of BaseLocalPlanner and I want to set a path to my move_base.

My problem is that move_base::make_plan give me a nav_msgs::path and move_base use base_local_planner::Trajectory to execute a path.

so from my move_base::Path the x, y, and theta velocities of the trajectory are missing

Is there a way to use my nav_msgs::path to generate a base_local_planner::Trajectory?

thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/188762/from-nav_msgs::path-to-base_local_planner::trajectory--?/) by [GuillaumeB](https://answers.ros.org/users/19670/guillaumeb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 312 on 2014-08-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The process of converting Paths to Trajectories is what the BaseLocalPlanners do.

**Edit**: Sorry, I misunderstood the question at first. Converting Paths to *Twist Commands* is what BaseLocalPlanners do.

In general you cannot convert arbitrary paths to Trajectories since a trajectory is the result of applying a certain velocity command for a given period of time. Paths can be arbitrarily complicated, and therefore cannot be translated to Trajectories. What is it you are trying to do with the Paths?

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2014-08-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [GuillaumeB](https://answers.ros.org/users/19670/guillaumeb/) on 2014-08-04**:
I don't find any function for this . I find only function to convert a goal into trajectory. Do you have the name of the function used?

**Comment by [GuillaumeB](https://answers.ros.org/users/19670/guillaumeb/) on 2014-08-04**:
My move_base subscribe to a path and I want that my robot follow up this path.